# Can we consider Computer Systyem(as a whole) as HID(Human Interface Device)?

Tags: hardware, computer-science, hid

In a discussion related to HID, I came across this question.

As per the standard definition or in any modified way, Can we consider Computer System (as a whole) as HID(Human Interface Device)    ???

Answer (score 0):

A device is a peripheral attached to a host computer, but not part of it. So no a Computer System is not a HID. A computer system interacts with a human and gives output to him but is not a device per definition.

Comment: Do you know any way by which we can make it work as hid device?